# Python: Inserting string into Mysql Database

Tags: python, mysql

I am using Python with Mysql.

I have a string that looks something like this:

s = "1.xxxxxxxxx 2.xxxxxxxxx 3.xxxxxxxxx"

Now I want to insert this string in db with one line in one row. For example

1. xxxxxxx
2. xxxxxxx
3. xxxxxxx

Each line gets inserted into a separate row.

How can I do this?

This is the code for making calls to database

```
def test(sql):

cursor = db.cursor()
try:

    cursor.execute(sql)

    db.commit()
except:

    db.rollback()
db.close()
```

This is the code that I am using to extract something from a pdf

```
def extract():
    string =convert_pdf_to_txt("sample.pdf")
    lines = list(filter(bool, string.split('1.')))
    Data = {}
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if 'References' in lines[i]:
        Data = (lines[i + 1])
        # print (Data)
        x= "INSERT INTO `ref` (`Reference`) VALUES" + '(' + '"{}"'.format(Data) + ')'
        test(x)
```

Comment: show your code.  Its hard to tell what is going wrong without code

Comment: @joelgoldstick :I have edited my question

Comment: So, `print (Data)` shows `"1.xxxxxxxxx 2.xxxxxxxxx 3.xxxxxxxxx"`, is that correct?

Comment: yes...I am trying to use Data.split('  ') which gives me 1.xxxxx2 xxxxxx3 xxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is properly split the string. In this case, if your example data is correct, you can accomplish this by splitting on the space character:

```
lines = string.split(' ')
```

Now, if I understand your code correctly, we need to insert only the lines that contain the string "References". Python provides easy syntax for this:

```
for i in lines:
    if 'References' in i:
        x = 'INSERT INTO `ref` (`Reference`) '
            'VALUES ({})'.format(i)
        test(x)
```

This assumes that your test() function is correct (it looks to be but I don't have a way of testing it right now).

Also, make sure you trust the data you are inserting as you are not doing input checking or sanitization. This is probably fine if you're just trying too process a PDF that you've already looked at to ensure its formatted correctly.

Editing to mention one more thing that struck me: If splitting the string on space doesn't handle your input data correctly, you may need to look at a more sophisticated way of identifying and splitting the entries. Regular expressions may help or may be more trouble than they're worth. Its hard to say without a more complete test data set.